# menu 2 result to use for SQL search

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Sorry if this is not clear but I am very new to this and am having trouble understanding the use of jQuery and php/mySQL.
My problem is that I have successfully populated 2 menus dynamically from database tables using jquery. Now I need to be able to use the selection of menu 2 to query my database. I just cant seem to be able to retrieve the contents of the chosen field in menu 2 in the right format to use. 
Below is my attempt:

select.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("select#exercise").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $("select#category").change(function() {
        $("select#exercise").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("select#exercise").html("<option>wait...</option>");
        var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("select_exercise.php", {
          id: id
        }, function(data) {
          $("select#exercise").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("select#exercise").html(data);
        });
      });
      $("form#select_form").submit(function() {
        var cat = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
        var type = $("select#exercise option:selected").attr('value');
        if (cat > 0 && type > 0) {
          var result = $("select#exercise option:selected").html();
          $("#result").html('your choice: ' + result);
        } else {
          $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
  <form action="process.php" id="select_form" method="post">
    Choose a category:
    <br />
    <select id="category">
      <?php echo $opt->ShowCategory(); ?>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />Choose a :
    <br />
    <select id="exercise">
      <option value="0">choose...</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <div id="result"></div>

  <!-- Trying to get result from menu2 to use in process.php sor sql query -->
  <script>
    < div id = "resultsContainer" > < /div>

    $(document).ready(function(){
       / / alert('jQuery loaded');
    $('#select_form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault;
    resultvalue = $('#result')[0].selectedIndex;
    $.post('process.php', {
      result: resultvalue
    }).done(function(data) {
      alert(data);
    })
    return false;
    })
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

process.php

```html
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "myDB";

mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
mysql_select_db($db) OR die("can not select the database $db");

$result = $_POST["result"];
$sql = "SELECT aim1,aim2,aim3,aim4 FROM exercise WHERE NAME = $result";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
echo '<table class="table">';
echo '<thead>';
echo"<tr><th>Communication</th></tr>";
echo '</thead><tbody>'; 
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo $row['aim1'];
echo "</td></tr><tr><td>";   
echo $row['aim2'];
echo "</td></tr><tr><td>";    
echo $row['aim3'];
echo "</TD></tr>";
echo "</td></tr><tr><td>";  
echo $row['aim4'];  
echo "</td></tr></tbody></table>";    
}     
?>
echo $sql;
```

Showing: "Notice: Undefined index: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\process.php on line 10"
I would be even happier if I could use the value of "result" without leaving the select.php page.
Any help would be much appreciated.